# Emacs subword-mode not working

Tags: emacs

In my Emacs `init.el` I have only the line `(setq subword-mode t)`. When I use `M-f` and `M-b` in a word like `WriteToFile` it doesn't move point between subwords. When I do `M-x subword-mode` it disables it, so it was on. When I re-enable it, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [solution](/questions/24226127/emacs-subword-mode-not-working#24226128) of calling `(subword-mode 1)` instead of setting `(setq subword-mode t)` is correct.

The problem was that when you run `M-x subword-mode` it *thinks* it was on, because you had set the variable which is intended to hold this status. Therefore it runs the code to disable the mode, even though it wasn't enabled.

From the manual:

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs) Minor Modes` <kbd>RET</kbd>

> Most minor modes also have a "mode variable", with the same name as the mode command. Its value is non-`nil` if the mode is enabled, and `nil` if it is disabled. **In general, you should not try to enable or disable the mode by changing the value of the mode variable directly in Lisp; you should run the mode command instead.** However, setting the mode variable through the Customize interface<sup>1</sup> will always properly enable or disable the mode, since Customize automatically runs the mode command for you.

<sup>1</sup> see: `(emacs) Easy Customization`

Answer (score 5):

Try adding
`(global-subword-mode 1)`
to your emacs file, it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Use this in the init file instead:

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
               (lambda () (subword-mode 1)))
```

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is so short. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?